# Meteor cordova plugin webapp fails to build on Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova, meteor

I got the same issue as [this guy](https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp/issues/5)

And [this thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/issue-with-cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp-after-upgrade-to-meteor-1-3/20314/10)

[image: Errors]

When running my app as meteor run ios-device and then trying to run it form Xcode8, it  throws a lot of issues.

Tried setting the swift version to legacy support in the build settings for the project without luck, also bumped the version from 1.2.8 to 1.3.0, didn't work.

It seems it could be fixed by changing to swift3 branch but I don't know how to do this since this package is being pulled by Atmosphere, so it's probably selecting master branch from npm and overriding the files each time I try to run it with meteor run ios-device

This is the [Broken Package Github Repo](https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing meteor add will override the default plugin version that comes with Meteor, you just need to point to the specific commit. Taken from https://forums.meteor.com/t/ios-10-compatibility/26065/17

meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5

Comment: Thanks for this. I wish there were fewer obscure hacks like these when developing using Meteor. :(

Comment: is there a way to do that nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

As suggestet by erikwall, but instead of

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp.git#8bf95eed3f313299fc2de33658866278eea2cdc5
```

just do:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-meteor-webapp@latest
```

For me did work just with latest

Comment: that is the new fix, when i asked the question the selected answer was the right choice, he actually deleted that commit now.